# Is using Titan Graph DB the right choice?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, datastax, titan

I am planning to use Titan Graph DB for my project.
The reason for selecting it is because it is the only graph database which can use DynamoDB as the storage backend. Thus I can free myself of the scalability/throughput worries.
But when I am trying to find any tutorial to get started with Titan, I am not finding many of them. This makes me doubt whether to use Titan or choose another graph database, like Neo4j or OrientDB.

Can someone tell me if Titan being used widely?
Is the community active?
Can I expect proper releases?

The last blogpost on [ThinkAurelius](https://thinkaurelius.com/blog/) is dated Feb 3, 2015 regarding acquisition by DataStax. DataStax website has no mentioning about Titan.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is more of an opinion question which might be suited for a different forum, but I will attempt to answer the main questions you stated anyway.

1. Is Titan being used widely? This is hard to tell since Aurelius doesn't disclose much information publicly about their users other than their [client list](https://thinkaurelius.com/affiliations/). The Amazon Fulfillment gave a [session](http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/dat203-building-graph-databases-on-aws) on their usage of Titan with DynamoDB. This [blog post](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2015/08/titan-graphdb-integration-in-dynamodb.html) identifies NASA's Jet Propulsion Laboratory and AdAgility as users also.
2. Is the community active? Somewhat. There are discussions occurring on the Titan [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/aureliusgraphs) and new messages come in every day. Commits are being made on the [`titan11`](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/tree/titan11) stream in GitHub. The most recent commit was on April 4, 2016.
3. Can I expect proper releases? "Expecting" releases of software is not something I would recommend in general. Software (both open source and proprietary) is released when the maintainers think the code is ready. For Titan specifically, the core maintainers have largely been absent from the community because they are busy working on [DataStax Enterprise Graph](http://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise-graph).

Comment: For further discussion on Titan's future, please make use of this Aurelius mailing list thread https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/R0RJnvVbgCs/vkYEsXD3HgAJ